# heroku subdomains on different apps?

Tags: heroku, subdomain, heroku-toolbelt

If you have a domain name pointed at heroku can you use it with subdomains across heroku apps?  If so where can I find info about how to set this up?

**main website - heroku app**

```
    www.mydomainname.com
```

**game site - different heroku app**

```
    game.mydomainname.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each subdomain should be a `CNAME` to the Heroku app you want.

In your DNS provider (something like GoDaddy, DNSimple, et. al), setup like so:

**subdomain | record type | end point**
www | CNAME | main-app.heroku.com
game | CNAME | other-app.heroku.com

Make sure you add the matching domain to the corresponding app with `$ heroku domains:add`

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Is this answer still valid. I'm having a lot of trouble getting aws to achieve this?

Comment: same with namecheep...